# How to mark a version as released in JIRA?

Tags: jira

I have created a few "versions" of my application. The first version (0.1.0) has been released. However I am not sure how I can mark it as "released" in JIRA.
When I go to the administration view. I see:

- Versions: Unreleased
- Name  Release date
- Unreleased 0.1.0  11/May/14
- Unreleased 0.2.0  30/Jun/14
- Unreleased 0.3.0
- Unreleased 0.2.1  Today
- Unreleased 0.4.0

I've looked around the GUI but haven't been able to figure out how to transition 0.1.0 into "released" status.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to go to the agile classic planning board of the project, and then click on the cogwheel on the right hand side in the version list.

Another is to go the the Project overview page (Projects->Your Project), select Versions on the left side, click "Manage Versions" on the top right and then hover over the corresponding version to find the cogwheel.